# R- Speed up calculation related with subset of data.table

Tags: r, performance, function, data.table, subset

Need help on speed up for case below:

I am having roughly 8.5 Millions rows of orders history for 1.3M orders. I need to calculate the time it take between two steps of each order. I use calculation as below:

```
History[, time_to_next_status:=
                      get_time_to_next_step(id_sales_order_item_status_history,
                                            id_sales_order_item, History_subset),
    by='id_sales_order_item_status_history']
```

In the code above:

- **id_sales_order_item** - id of a sales order item - there are multiple history record have the same id_sales_order_item
- **id_sales_order_item_status_history** - id of a row
- **History_subset** is a subset of **History** which contains only 3 columns `[id_sales_order_item_status_history, id_sales_order_item, created_at]`  needed in the calculations.
- **created_at** is the time the history was created

The function **get_time_to_next_step** is defined as below

```
get_time_to_next_step <- function(id_sales_order_item_status_history, filter_by,
                                  dataSet){

   dataSet <- dataSet %.% filter(id_sales_order_item == filter_by)

   index <- match(currentId, dataSet$id_sales_order_item_status_history)

   time_to_next_status <- dataSet[index + 1, created_at] - dataSet[index, created_at]

   time_to_next_status
}
```

The issues is that it take 15mins to run arround 10k records of the History. So it would take up to ~9 days to complete the calculation. Is there anyway I can fasten this up without break the data in to multiple subset?

Comment: Could you please post some sample input/desired output?  I think that would be most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will take a shot.  Can't you try something like this..

```
History[ , Index := 1:.N, by= id_sales_order_item]
History[ , time_to_next_status := created_at[Index+1]-created_at[Index], by= id_sales_order_item]
```

I would think this would be pretty fast.

Comment: Thank you - I was just about to edit "current_id" to "id_sales_order_item".

It is pretty fast. just run and it reached 1M rows in 5mins

Comment: Interesting...i am a little surprised it is still that slow.  Maybe a ```lag``` operation and then the subtraction would be faster.  But I am not positive.

Comment: Why not simply `History[, time_to_next_status := c(NA,diff(created_at)), by = id_sales_order_item]`.

Comment: @Mike, I tracked it wrongly, as the data is grouped by 
`id_sales_order_item` and when it reach 1M counts it mean it have go over 1M `id_sales_order_item` which is about 6~7M records of History. I don't know how can lag help in this cases.Thanks mnel - I just tested your formula and they are great fast - thought the result was not what I wanted as now it is `time_since_last_status`.